# Connecting multiple javascript elements together with data-attributes (JSFiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that works when I only have one element on the page, but with multiple items I don't know how to pair each item to its corresponding image.

In this JSFiddle, what I currently have is laid out. When you hover over "link 3" it is behaving properly, the image is supposed to appear under the mouse while hovering over the link. But when I hover over the other links, they don't know which item to make visible.

I can pass unique slugs to any of the items in the links. Does anyone know the best way to properly connect each item?

https://jsfiddle.net/xw2Lvvj7/

```js
var $img = $('.image');
$img.hide();
$('.hidden-overlay').mousemove(function(e) {
  $img.stop(1, 1).fadeIn();
  $('.image').offset({
    top: e.pageY - ($img.outerHeight() / 2),
    left: e.pageX - ($img.outerWidth() / 2)
  });
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $img.fadeOut();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 90px;
}

.link {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hidden-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a class="link" data-slug="1">
        link 1
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');" data-slug="1"></div>
        <div class="hidden-overlay" data-slug="1"></div>
      </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="link" data-slug="2">
        link 2
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/450x450');" data-slug="2"></div>
        <div class="hidden-overlay" data-slug="2"></div>
      </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="link" data-slug="3">
        link 3
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');" data-slug="3"></div>
        <div class="hidden-overlay" data-slug="3"></div>
      </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find each of their `.image` classes parents to something like this:

```js
var $img = $('.image');
$img.hide();
$('.hidden-overlay').mousemove(function(e) {

  // Find the [.image] classes inside the [.link] parent classes for every .hidden-overlay 
  var oImageHover = $(this).parents('.link').find('.image'); 
  oImageHover.stop(1, 1).fadeIn();
  oImageHover.offset({
    top: e.pageY - (oImageHover.outerHeight() / 2),
    left: e.pageX - (oImageHover.outerWidth() / 2)
  });
}).mouseleave(function() {
  // The same thing as well when the element was out of focus
  var oImageLeave = $(this).parents('.link').find('.image');
  oImageLeave.fadeOut();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 90px;
}

.link {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hidden-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a class="link" data-slug="1">
    link 1
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');" data-slug="1"></div>
    <div class="hidden-overlay" data-slug="1"></div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="link" data-slug="2">
    link 2
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/450x450');" data-slug="2"></div>
    <div class="hidden-overlay" data-slug="2"></div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="link" data-slug="3">
    link 3
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');" data-slug="3"></div>
    <div class="hidden-overlay" data-slug="3"></div>
  </a>

  <body>
```

Hope this helps for your case